# ng-selected not working with ng-options but works fine with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam using `ng-selected`, `ng-value`, `ng-options`. But I am unable to select the value, `ng-selected` not working

```
  <select  name="team_selected" 
    required="" ng-model="edit_team_name" ng-change="edit_selectTeam(edit_team_name)" 
    ng-selected='edit_team_id === team.team_id' ng-value="team.team_id" 
    ng-options="team.team_name for team in teamNameAvailable track by team.team_id">                                
  </select>
```

Comment: You are applying `ng-selected` to the `<select>` tag, not an `<option>` within it, which doesn't make sense. `ng-repeat` constructs an `<option>` element so `ng-selected` will work there.

Comment: @Piyush can you able to post your controller and data

Answer (score 0):

```
<select  name="team_selected" required="" ng-model="edit_team_name" ng-change="edit_selectTeam(edit_team_name)" >   
<option ng-repeat="team.team_name for team in teamNameAvailable track by team.team_id"  ng-selected='edit_team_id === team.team_id'  ng-value="team.team_id"></option                             
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I have created a default value with selected in select box

instead of doing `edit_team_id === team.team_id` this `ng-model` itself will select the select value form options

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.teamNameAvailable=[{
                              team_id:1,
                              team_name:"USA"
                          },{
                              team_id:2,
                              team_name:"India"
                          },{
                              team_id:3,
                              team_name:"Aus"
                         }];

$scope.edit_team_name=$scope.teamNameAvailable[1];
});
```

```css
select{
width:150;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<select  name="team_selected" 
    required="" ng-model="edit_team_name" ng-change="edit_selectTeam(edit_team_name)" 
    ng-options="team.team_name for team in teamNameAvailable track by team.team_id">                                
  </select>
  </div>
```